# Connect azure web app to VNET using ARM template and avoid manual Sync Network

Tags: azure, networking

I have already provisioned VNET with VPN gateway with VM, which hosts service on port 2000. I am provisioning a web app, which is connected to VNET on provisioning time (in Ibiza portal both at web app and web app service in tab Networking I see that my web app is connected to VNET). However, if I will use Kudu console and try to reach my service on port 2000 (tcpping 10.4.0.3:2000) - I'll receive an error, stating that socket is used in incorrect way. I can fix it by using 'Sync network' on my web app hosting plan ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet ) - but, this is not automatic action. And what is interesting - my deployment consists of several web app in several web app hosting plans, but I need to run Sync network on only one of web app hosting plans. Is it possible to Sync network automatically after adding web app to it?

Here is part of template, which is used for provisioning:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "name": "[variables('webappName')]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('webApiVersion')]",
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
    "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
    "siteConfig": {
      "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
      "alwaysOn": true,
      "webSocketsEnabled": true,
      "phpVersion": "",
      "defaultDocuments": [
        "index.html"
      ]
    }
  },
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]" ],
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "type": "virtualNetworkConnections",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webappName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "vnetResourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('vnetSubscriptionId') ,'/resourceGroups/', parameters('vnetResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is an issue on github which describes my scenario: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3391

Comment: you tried passing that to the template?

Comment: Yes, I tried to pass resyncRequired on sites level - this does not helped (sorry, left this task yesterday, feeling being destroyed while trying to figure this out).

Comment: I would expect it to not be possible in that case.

Comment: It's a pity then :(